# From SQL to Excel date format

Tags: php, excel, sqlite, date

I have found a code that helped me get an Excel table of my DB, it works fine with all the columns except a "date" column it just gives me #######.

This "date" column is DATETIME type in sqlite (it by default enters the current date (yyyy-mm-dd)), the data comes from an input type date from HTML.

here's my PHP code :

```
<?php
namespace Chirp;
include "./_pdo.php";
$db_file = "./test.sqlite";
PDO_Connect("sqlite:$db_file");

$data = PDO_FetchAll("SELECT * FROM test");
  // Original PHP code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
  // Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.
 function cleanData(&$str)
  {
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
  }

  // file name for download
  $filename = "website_data_" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
  header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

  $flag = false;
  foreach($data as $row) {
    if(!$flag) {
      // display field/column names as first row
      echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
      $flag = true;
    }
    array_walk($row, __NAMESPACE__ . '\cleanData');
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
  }

  exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll kick yourself...

Make the date column wider in Excel ;-)

Comment: I can rest in peace now